# active list in sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hi guys need help on designing my sidebar ... i want to have an active state in my sidebar using javascript... 
and i tried the `element.css()` to give it style after it is clicked 
but after i clicked the list my hover style from css is gone, im guessing its because i changed the color after it is clicked and there is no returning back to its original design.

```js
var sideNav = $('.sideNav');
$('#dashboard').click(function() {
  sideNav.css({
    'color': '#8c8c8c',
    'background-color': '#373942'
  });
  $('#dashboard').css({
    'color': '#ccc',
    'background-color': '#515461'
  });
});
$('#customers').click(function() {
  sideNav.css({
    'color': '#8c8c8c',
    'background-color': '#373942'
  });
  $('#customers').css({
    'color': '#ccc',
    'background-color': '#515461'
  });
});
$('#items').click(function() {
  sideNav.css({
    'color': '#8c8c8c',
    'background-color': '#373942'
  });
  $('#items').css({
    'color': '#ccc',
    'background-color': '#515461'
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #373942;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 230px;
}

.sidebar ul {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar li {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background-color: red;*/
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  /*margin-left: 20px;*/
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
  background-color: #515461;
  color: #ccc;
  border-left: 4px solid #8c8c8c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li id="dashboard" class="sideNav">Dashboard</li>
    <li id="customers" class="sideNav">Customers</li>
    <li id="items" class="sideNav">Items</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline styles for highlighting buttons when you click, you should define a class to represent an active button and then use `toggleClass` or a combination of `addClass` and `removeClass` functions to get this done.

Here's a fiddle to get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/hwwy8yhL/2/

CSS

```
.sidebar {
  background-color: #373942;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 230px;
}

.sidebar ul {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar li {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background-color: red;*/
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  /*margin-left: 20px;*/
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
  background-color: #515461;
  color: #ccc;
  border-left: 4px solid #8c8c8c;
}

.sidebar li.active
{
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #515461
}
```

JS

```
var sideNav = $('.sideNav');
$('#dashboard').click(function() {
  sideNav.removeClass('active');
  $('#dashboard').addClass('active');
});
$('#customers').click(function() {
  sideNav.removeClass('active');
  $('#customers').addClass('active');
});
$('#items').click(function() {
  sideNav.removeClass('active');
  $('#items').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using below jQuery function and css

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li id="dashboard" class="sideNav">Dashboard</li>
    <li id="customers" class="sideNav">Customers</li>
    <li id="items" class="sideNav">Items</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.sideNav').click(function() {
  $('.sideNav').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**css**

```
.sidebar {
  background-color: #373942;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 230px;
}
.sidebar ul {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.sidebar li {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
.sidebar li:hover{
  border-left: 4px solid #8c8c8c;   
}
.sidebar li:hover, .sidebar li.active{
  background-color: #515461;
  color: #ccc;

}
```

Click [here](https://codepen.io/gvreddys99/pen/oWWLKX) for your complete snippet in codepen